# Appcelerator WebView unable to locate / load png resource on iOS

Tags: webview, appcelerator

I get the following exception in the html / js source. The pngs are copied over with an assets folder and run in webviews outside of appcelerator just fine.

```
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I apologize for the screenshots below, but it is difficult to capture the logs from the safari debug console and convey the file tree in Appcelerator Studio.

Here is a screenshot of the full exception from the safari debug console.

[image]

You can see the png resources placed in the directory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `<use-app-thinning>false</use-app-thinning>` inside your tiapp.xml. If you open the folder from your error message you'll see that it doesn't copy over the subfolders. Disableing `app-thinning` will work as a workaround. Tested it on Android (is working correctly) and iOS simulator 11 with Titanum 9.1.0.GA